# Get the entire stack trace in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to get the entire stack trace in Node?  The following script should print 100 items, but only prints 10.  Note, it *does* work in Chrome, just not in Node.  (To run the snippet below and see results, you'll actually need to open the browser's dev tools.)

```js
function trace(depth = 100) {
  if (!depth) {
    console.trace();
  } else {
    trace(depth - 1);
  }
}

trace();
```

I've also tried the `new Error().stack` method, but this prints the same limited number of lines.  Unlike `stack.trace()` this method also only displays 10 items in Chrome.

```js
function trace(depth = 100) {
  if (!depth) {
    console.info(new Error().stack);
  } else {
    trace(depth - 1);
  }
}

trace();
```

The debugger knows the entire stack trace, not to mention the JS engine itself needs to be able to walk the stack for closures, so there must be a way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your code, you need to declare:

```js
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
```

This works for both methods in the OP.

Comment: but this cannot catch where the error be thrown lastly in my code.
It only stops at the function method of package that I used.